# Non-blocking requests in Sanic framework

Tags: python, python-asyncio, sanic

I'm trying out [Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic) and ran the Hello World app except I added a sleep in the request handler:

```
@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    time.sleep(5)
    return json({"hello": "world"})
```

However, when I run this, it still blocks on each request:

```
$ python app.py
2017-02-18 19:15:22,242: INFO: Goin' Fast @ http://0.0.0.0:8000
2017-02-18 19:15:22,245: INFO: Starting worker [15867]
```

In two separate terminals:

```
$ time curl http://0.0.0.0:8000/
{"hello":"world"}
real    0m5.009s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.001s

$ time curl http://0.0.0.0:8000/
{"hello":"world"}
real    0m9.459s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

I thought the idea of Sanic is being able to process all requests asynchronously and not blocking until one completes to process the next one. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace `time.sleep(5)` with:

```
 await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Ahhh, duh, everything within the handler must be non-blocking as well. Thanks!